# Have semigroups with actions on themselves that have a dual to the compatibility axiom ever been studied?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups, monoid

[Update: I've now asked the same question on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/243022/have-semigroups-with-actions-on-themselves-that-have-a-dual-to-the-compatibility).]

For a semigroup $G$ with a left action *on itself*, the axiom for compatibility becomes:

$$
\forall f,g,h\in G:hg(f)=h(g(f))
$$

Now suppose there is additional axiom, or constraint if you prefer, called consistency:

$$
\forall f,g\in G: f(g)f=g(f)g
$$

This can be represented by a commutative diagram:

[image]

If I chain two of these diagrams together I get the following:

[image]

The consistency of $f$ and $hg$ can be represented by the following:

[image]

Comparing these last two commutative diagrams suggests the following two identities:

$$
\left.
\begin{array}{l}
hg(f)=h(g(f))\\
(hg)=g(f)(h)f(g)
\end{array}
\right\}
$$

The first is compatibility of course but now there is a second identity which suggests that compatibility has a dual if we require consistency.

These identities have applications in rewriting theory, however it has been suggested to me that a semigroup or monoid with a consistent left action on itself may have interesting mathematical properties in its own right. Is this true? Have semigroups or monoids such as this ever been studied?

Comment: I'm also wondering whether this question wouldn't be better on mathoverflow but don't want to get marked negatively yet again.

Comment: It does sound like mathoverflow material if your interesting characteristics are indeed interesting, but we can't guess now can we?

Comment: Okay, I've rewritten the question pretty extensively.

Comment: What side is the group action from? I can't make the condition make sense.

Comment: I know it is a bit confusing. The group action is from the left, since the order of the elements stays the same, even though the notation suggests it is from the right.

Comment: I think the condition might be more clear if you added the parenthesis to it (they are not needed for specifying the condition, but I think they would make it easier to read).

Comment: Sorry, whereabouts exactly? You mean $\tau;(\rho\backslash\tau)=\rho;(\tau\backslash\rho)$?

Comment: Hmm, actually now I don't see how it makes sense any more. You have $\tau\backslash\rho$ but $\tau$ was from the group, not the monoid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41579/discussion-between-james-smith-and-tobias-kildetoft).

Comment: I honestly think this is incredibly confusing. (I am not trying to be arrogant, just admitting my confusion.) Perhaps a better notation? I don't know.

Comment: Don't worry, I don't think you're being arrogant. However, you will have to be a bit more specific about what confuses you exactly. The only thing I can think of is that you find the backslash notation confusing. If you agree to this, I'm happy to change it.